# Ideal gas law vs van der Waals equation of gas

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, gas

$$ ( P + \frac{n^2 a}{V^2})(V-nb) =nRT$$

is the van der Waals equation of state

and,

$$ PV=nRT$$

is the ideal gas law.

Similar to how I asked in this [stack](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/577510/defining-the-ideal-gas-thermometer) , prof. Moungi Bawendi says that as we drop pressure to zero by some mechanism, the product of pressure and molar volume converges to some constant based on the temperature and uses this to define the ideal gas law.

Now, could we start from van der Waals equation and work back to a more accurate f(T) which converges more broadly than it does for an ideal gas? if so, how do we do it?

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by a *more accurate $f(T)$*. The right hand side of van der Waals equation of state is $nRT$, exactly like in the perfect gas equation of state. In any case, have a look to my answer to  your previous question.

Comment: since there are those 'extra' correction factors, I think there would be other 'correction' factors on the right hand side of the equation

Comment: There is not. However it is neither obvious nor intuitive. Only a  systematic derivation of van der Waals equation of state as a mean field limit of the exact equation of state of a classical fluid is able to show that there is no correction to the right hand side.